# How to set integer value in PFQuery where query?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

I have integrated **Parse** in my iOS apps.

I want to know how can I set integer value in where query as below;

```
int userID =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"USER_ID"];

PFQuery *querypush = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EndCall"];
[querypush whereKey:@"UserId" equalTo:userID];
```

`"UserId"` column is of `Number` data type.

I can set string value but I can not set int value.

I have searched a lot but I could not find the solution.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Add @ before your int so it look like @222 for example , when u read this property you need to cast it from NSNumber

Comment: To set this integer into your query , u can write [NSNumber numberWithInt:userID]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to list the value as an object, which will mean an `NSNumber` in this case. Your code will look like this:

```
PFQuery *querypush = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EndCall"];
[querypush whereKey:@"UserId" equalTo:@(userID)];
```

`NSNumber` can resolve to a lot of different primitive types, including `int`, but the Parse server needs the `NSNumber` type to resolve properly.

Answer (score 2):

You may get the `user_id` as a `[PFUser currentUser].objectId]` so you may set a query by following:

```
PFQuery *querypush = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EndCall"];
[querypush whereKey:@"UserId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId]];
```